# Graph CacheAttached method

Tags: acumatica

I want to make the SOLine Qty field to 1.0 by default, so I have changed at DAC level, by doing this it will be applied to the entire application?

Next, I can do same by writing Graph CacheAttached method also, I think this will apply only to that particular graph and if the same field is used in another graph or a custom new screen this will not affect in that graph.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, adding an attribute to SOLine DAC extension will apply this attribute system wide. To limit its scope to a graph, use a CacheAttached.

Here are good reads on this subject :

**DAC** : https://help.acumatica.com/(W(12))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=b3d24079-bda4-4f82-9fbd-c444a8bcb733

**Append and replace of dacs attributes** : http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/01/append-and-replace-of-dacs-attributes.html

These concepts are well explained in the T200 certification, which I suggest you do if you haven't already.